# CRT AND C++ SOFT

Tags: c++, crt

I don't understand why when you build a c++ soft you need to link in the C runtime library?
Is it because standard c++ library use it ?

Comment: Depends on the implementation, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts with main(), runtime support code is needed to pass the argc and argv arguments and do something with the return value.  Etcetera.  That code lives in the CRT.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And the standard C library, which is part of C++ too. And maybe other things generated by the compiler.

Comment: C runtime library and standard C library are two distinct thing ?

Comment: The Wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library actually offers some insights on the differences.

Answer (score 0):

C++ was designed to maintain as much C compatability as possible. That means that they had to include the C standard library. The C standard library is also included by a lot of platform-dependent or library headers. Without those header files, for example, you would be unable to include many of the OS-specific headers on either Linux or Windows (Windows.h, etc.). Also, as stated above, C++ maintains the same method of calling the main() function for compatibility.